# Unable to start basic application using sencha 2. Library files are not loaded

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

[image]I am a new bee to sencha 2.I wanted to run a basic application using sencha touch but unable to load the application.

Here is what I have done.

I have downloaded the notesApp from miamicoder and i am trying to run the first chapter.

I have attached the folder structure in the screenshot. Please have a look to understand the folder structure.

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Notes</title>
    <link href="sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="sencha-touch-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I have downloaded sencha sdk 2.1 and took sencha-touch-debug.js and sencha-touch.css and placed in the root of the folder and referred from index.html as mentioned below. I used to to the same thing in sencha 1 and I was getting success but I am getting below error if I am trying to do the same with sencha 2.

I am getting errors as below.

```
Failed to load resource file:///path/NotesApp-Book-Code-Ch1/src/event/Dispatcher.js?_dc=1354982532236
Failed to load resource file:///path/NotesApp-Book-Code-Ch1/src/event/publisher/Dom.js?_dc=1354982532238
Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading 'file:///path/ebook-building-a-sencha-touch-2-app%20(1)/NotesApp-Book-Code-Ch1/src/event/Dispatcher.js', please verify that the file exists sencha-touch-debug.js:8324
Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading 'file:///path/ebook-building-a-sencha-touch-2-app%20(1)/NotesApp-Book-Code-Ch1/src/event/publisher/Dom.js', please verify that the file exists
```

Is it necessary to use senchatools and generate folder structure? Simply copying the two lib files (sencha-touch-debug.js and sencha-touch.css) and refer them from index.html will not work with sencha 2?

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Working with Sencha touch 2 needs to include the complete SDK in the project folder not only 2 library files like sencha 1. Including the complete framework will solve the issue.

Thanks